# [Help]: Three.js coordinates translation

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to move default drawing postion of three.js (0,0,0) center of canvas to actual canvas start ?

For instance, here: https://jsfiddle.net/data_x/mwprgnra/8/

I want to move the lines to start of the dashed canvas box. (shift from 3d coordinates to 2d coordinates position). I need this because i want to overlay svg canvas over webgl canvas. For this i need both of them to follow same coordinate positions.

Some part of code:

```
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( w / - 2, w / 2, h / 2, h / - 2, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
```

Any hints/help are much appreciated,

Thank you,

Comment: you need to scale your data from min,max actual to min,max displayed

Comment: i tried multiplying with (canvas.height/2 - 60) for the return value of commented out setrange function in above code but nothing was rendered apart from axis and the axis size was decreased strangely. Is this because i am using perspective camera for 2d drawing ?

Comment: the scale computations are easier if you use an orthographic camera (i.e. linear algebra).

Comment: wont the line positions gets changed if i scale ? can you please point some examples ?

Comment: Changed to ortho..plot is almost looking same as with perspective with minute changes to increase spacing and line length. i thought that even these changes are not necessary.

Comment: Got it. Normalizing formula is correct. I messed with data. Taking min max for each array whereas i want to take for each column. And i updated the question by removing one part of my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I played around a bit changing:

OrthographicCamera( left, right, top, bottom, near, far )

left — Camera frustum left plane. - set to 0

right — Camera frustum right plane. - set to canvas width

top — Camera frustum top plane. - set to canvas height

bottom — Camera frustum bottom plane. - set to -400 (you need to change this accirding to your canvas width, height

near — Camera frustum near plane. - set to 50

far — Camera frustum far plane. - set to 100

As left is set to 0, it will be rendered at left most part of canvas. Adjusting the bottom accordingly, will move your objects to the top of canvas.